# TFS2010 ignores specific changeset number

Tags: msbuild

I want to build change set 3880 from my software using TFS 2010.

When I create a new build to the queue and set the parameter "Get Version" on the tab "Paramaters" to C3880 (or 3880 which should be the same), then TFS builds always the neweset sources (change set 3888) and not the requested 3880.

e.g. following http://blog.sublogic.com/2011/09/22/tfs-2010-building-an-older-changeset/1/

Is that a server problem or a configuration problem? Is there another place where someone could have set TFS to the latest sources (where?) ?

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display in VS is buggy. It seems that the right parameter is processed to the build server, but VS shows "current change set". I built an older change set and the output is "older".